# number of "equivalence relations" on a set with "n-elements"

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, equivalence-relations, set-partition, bell-numbers

I am trying to find a formula for number of equivalence relations on a set with n-elements however I am confused.  
I have already encountered the idea of "[bell's number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number)" and "[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)" however it seems to contradict the meaning of "Relation".  
Definition: "Relation" between sets A and B, to be any subset of Cartesian product $A\times B$  
Definition: "Equivalence Relation" is a relation that is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.  
So, if we suppose that we want to find "equivalence relations" on the set $A=\{a,b,c\}$ we would have the following:  
$\{(a,a)\}$  
$\{(b,b)\}$  
$\{(c,c)\}$  
$\{(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)\}$  
$\{(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b)\}$  
$\{(a,a),(a,c),(c,a),(c,c)\}$  
$\{(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,c)\}$  
$\{(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b),(c,c)\}$  
$\{(a,a),(a,c),(c,a),(c,c),(b,b)\}$  
$\{(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,c),(a,a)\}$  
$\{(b,b),(a,a),(c,c),(b,a),(a,b),(a,c),(c,a),(b,c),(c,b)\}$  
which is $11$, however the $B_3=5$ which even if I recursively sum we arrive at $B_1+B_2+B_3=1+2+5=8$.  
So, aren't the sets I presented "equivalence relations" on $A$ or the formula I am looking for is different?

Comment: Neither $\{(a,a)\}$ nor $\{(b,b)\}$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ because they are not reflexive.

Comment: Reflexivity means that $xRx$ for any $x$.

Comment: To establish an equivalence relation is the same as to partition a set. So the answer is $B_n$. See the explanations for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703475/determine-the-number-of-equivalence-relations-on-the-set-1-2-3-4)